# How can I improve my attempt to create protected properties

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

```
#import "BGReviewController.h"

@interface BGReviewController (protected)
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *dislikeButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *likeButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *post;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cancel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@end
```

Then I add:

```
@synthesize backgroundImage = _backgroundImage;
@synthesize dislikeButton = _dislikeButton;
@synthesize likeButton = _likeButton;
@synthesize post = _post;
@synthesize cancel = _cancel;
@synthesize textView = _textView;
```

And I got error:
/business/Dropbox/badgers/BadgerNew/BGReviewController.m:32:13: Property declared in category 'protected' cannot be implemented in class implementation

Should I declare the synthesize in the implementation file of the category and then put the ivars explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

you cant @synthesize in a category, you have to do the getters and setter manually

[check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/879936/1219956)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`@interface BGReviewController (protected)`

With

`@interface BGReviewController ()`